# use correctly String#tr method?

Tags: crystal-lang

New to Crystal-lang, I'm actually trying to code a Caesar cipher.
Problem is, when I enter a string to encode, the program show the same string without modification.

```
if ARGV.size < 3
  puts "./caesarcipher [ed] [text] [num]"
  exit
end

letter = ARGV[0]
str = ARGV[1]
n = ARGV[2].to_i
alphabet = ("A".."Z").to_a

case letter
when "e" then puts str.tr(alphabet.join, alphabet.rotate(n).join)
when "d" then puts str.tr(alphabet.join, alphabet.rotate(n * -1).join)
else          puts "./caesarcipher [ed] [text] [num]"
end
```

Since the two arguments in the tr method contain what I want and tr must return a value, I don't understand why nothing change.

Comment: Just another random tip, you can use `-n` instead of `n * -1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

The reason why this didn't work for you, is because if you examine the `alphabet` array, it's actually only capital letters. So in your translation, you are only translating the upper case characters. If you instead change

`alphabet=("a".."z").to_a`

that will translate for the lower case characters.

If you want to do both, then I would suggest creating two "alphabets" one with upper and one with lower case letters, and then applying the translation twice on the string, one with upper and one with lower case alphabets.

Comment: Concatenating both ranges will result in uppercase letters being switched for lowercase ones in the extremes of the ranges. You should probably change both ranges individually while rotating.

Comment: yeah you're probably right. You could apply the translation in two steps. Alternatively you could have two "alphabets" and then you rotate and then join together.

Comment: Thanks, I was so focused on the tr than I didn't check this.